# List index out of range in tkinter

Tags: python, dataframe, exception, tkinter, stack

I'm getting an `"Exception in Tkinter callback"` when I try to run a program on a larger Excel file.

The program converts a column in the file which has hobbies data `", "` separated. I just need to split each value around `", "` in a new row keeping rest all columns the same as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dFTk.jpg)

Below is the code which is working perfectly for splitting if used directly:

```
Raw_Data_1 = (Raw_Data_1.set_index(Index_Raw_data_Columns_1).stack().str.split(' ✘', expand=True).stack().unstack(-2).reset_index(-1, drop=True).reset_index())
```

It gives me the below error when I tried running in Tkinter. It is strange when I tried running on a smaller file it runs perfectly but when file size increases it gives me this error.

```
**Exception in Tkinter callback**
**Traceback (most recent call last):**
  File "C:\Users\Shivaji Choursiya\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", **line 1705, in __call__**
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-5-c95adf78dd09>", **line 176, in Main**
    Raw_Data_1 = (Raw_Data_1.set_index(Index_Raw_data_Columns_1).stack().str.split(' ✘', expand=True).stack().unstack(-2).reset_index(-1, drop=True).reset_index())
  File "C:\Users\Shivaji Choursiya\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", **line 6245, in stack**
    return stack(self, level, dropna=dropna)
  File "C:\Users\Shivaji Choursiya\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py", **line 547, in stack**
    dtype = dtypes[0]
**IndexError: list index out of range**
```

Below error when Run code separately on file

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-d3e138bf57f9> in <module>
      4 Raw_Data_1 = (Raw_Data_1.set_index(Index_Raw_data_Columns_1)
      5    .stack()
----> 6    .str.split(' ✘', expand=True)
      7    .stack()
      8    .unstack(-2)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in stack(self, level, dropna)
   6243             return stack_multiple(self, level, dropna=dropna)
   6244         else:
-> 6245             return stack(self, level, dropna=dropna)
   6246 
   6247     def explode(self, column: Union[str, Tuple]) -> "DataFrame":

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py in stack(frame, level, dropna)
    545         # we concatenate instead.
    546         dtypes = list(frame.dtypes.values)
--> 547         dtype = dtypes[0]
    548 
    549         if is_extension_array_dtype(dtype):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `IndexError` seems pretty self-explanatory. What have you done to debug this?

Comment: Please have a look at how you can format code (e.g. select and press Ctrl+k). This enhances the readability of your post.

Comment: @BryanOakley  I tried making the File in which I got error to from 17k Rows to just 10 still the same error Pops up.
I have another file with 500 rows of data on which it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Ronald Thank you for your suggestion it really improved the Readability.